# Why does the gcc command not work on Windows command line, but works on Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, gcc, command, gcc-warning

I have added `C:\MinGW\bin` to my user path, and I made sure that gcc.exe exists in the `C:\MinGW\bin` folder.

When I run this I get:

> gcc -- version
>   'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

But when I run it on Git Bash, the command executes properly. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please show the exact code you are executing.

Comment: how do u add the path? can u add the result of `which gcc` in git bash?

Answer (score 0):

CMD.exe may still have your old %PATH% environment variable value.

If you've updated it in the Environment Variables tab under Computer / Properties, you might be able to close and re-open the command prompt to get the new environment variable value.

See [How do you add a Windows environment variable without rebooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting) on Server Fault.